# Adobe inDesign - Table rows cross page

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, tables, formatting

I'm trying to create a two-columns table on InDesign.

Unfortunally, when row content doesn't fit the remaining page space, the entire row is pushed on new page leaving a lot of space on previous page.

Is there a way to make rows continue on next page without splitting it?

I've tried to search on google and to set a lot of Cell Options like "Keep with next row", but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Normal text flow does not apply to tables, meaning you can't have rows automatically broken across consecutive pages to show partial content. If a cell is too high to fit, it *will* get pushed to the next page by default.

What you can do however is manually simulate this. Add another row and move some of that content there, so you can get what you need, but not in a single row, but two rows instead.